# Error when attempting to install theme in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, jar, themes, android-studio-3.0, windows-11

***Note***: I'm a *total* newbie in Android Studio/Java (really, my Google searches are stuff like "What is Gradle").

### Problem: error when attempting to install them into Android Studio

**TL;DR**
This is error I get when I attempt to import a theme (Windows 11):

> *Invalid File*  The file `C:\...\Downloads\file_name.jar` contains no settings to import.  Please make sure that it was generated by 'File | Manage IDE Settings | Export Settings...' feature.

**Here are the steps I'm doing to install a theme, up to the error:**

Download a theme in the form of a *.jar* file.  I went to [JetBrains Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=androidstudio&tags=Theme) to get the theme.  Note that you're asked to download a specific version of the theme, so I chose themes that correspond to the latest version of Android Studio, as that's what I have.  I also chose from the "free" selections.  Perhaps I did something wrong here?  I can't think of what, though, as it's fairly self-explanatory.

Next, go to **File >> Manage IDE Settings >> Import Settings**.  This opens a window called *Import File Location*, a file explorer.  Navigate to the *.jar* file you want to import, and select it. For this example, I navigate to my Downloads folder and select a file:

[image]

When I select it, this error pops up:
[image]

To me, this message makes *no sense*.  I'm not exporting anything! When I go to the *Exporting* page, it's just a standard way to export your settings. The *.jar* files that are downloaded aren't empty files.  Also, this appears to be an uncommon error -- at least, I couldn't find anything like this on the interwebs (but maybe I didn't use the best search queries).

I'm obviously doing something *very* wrong that'll be *very* obvious to me in retrospect.  Can someone tell me what that is?